# Controlling a stepper with MATLAB

Tags: arduino-uno, stepper

I am trying to control a 28BYJ-48 stepper motor + [ULN2003 motor driver module](https://www.gearbest.com/sensors/pp_599743.html?vip=2665035&gclid=Cj0KCQiAuZXQBRDKARIsAMwpUeROrehL2AfI3oWRb8Yw7jRadlRIDHFX0nwG455NeteX9R43xRfrP58aAlx_EALw_wcB)  (this is a [picture](https://cdn.instructables.com/F41/07VI/HMMF4YXL/F4107VIHMMF4YXL.MEDIUM.jpg)) using MATLAB.

I tried to follow the instructions on [this page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduinoio/ug/control-motors-using-adafruit-motor-shield-v2.html?searchHighlight=shield&s_tid=doc_srchtitle), but these instructions are specific to Adafruit MotorShield, and I couldn't understand how to modify the code to fit my motor/driver.

Specifically:

1. How do I wire my motor/driver/Arduino?
2. How do I modify this command:

   ```
   shield = addon(a, 'Adafruit\MotorShieldV2')
   ```
3. Do I need to flash my Arduino with any libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Adafruit Motor Shield V2](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/009/536/original/adafruit_products_mshieldv2schem.png?1396892649) itself generates signals that are required for motor control.

[ULN2003 motor driver module](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slrs027o/slrs027o.pdf) requires signals at the input. This is a significant difference.

[Example](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=357907.0) of use this driver with MATLAB. Not need to flash Arduino any libraries.

```
a=arduino('com3','uno);

pins={'D8', 'D9', 'D10', 'D11'};
steps={'1100', '0110', '0011','1001'};

steps_size=size(steps,2);                        %steps = 4

for i = 1:50

    step = steps{mod(i,steps_size)+1};      % step=1,2,3,4

    for j=1:4
        writeDigitalPin(a, pins{j}, str2double(step(j)));
    end

    %pause(0.01);

end
```

Wiring example (Copied from [CheapStepper v0.2](https://github.com/tyhenry/CheapStepper))
[image: Copied from [CheapStepper v0.2]]